# Springfox swagger ui support for java 7

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, springfox, jdk1.7

I am trying to integrate springfox swagger ui into my spring MVC project.
I have already integrated swagger 2.9.2 and it was working all fine.

Now I found out that this version does not support java 7 but I need this for one legacy project.
From release notes it was clear that 2.9.0 will be last version supporting java 7.

My question is -

If I have only basic swaggerconfig, will I have to change anything if I migrate downward to 2.9.0 ?

UPDATE 1 - version 2.9.1 does not support Java 7.
and on version 2.9.0, its giving error of "Unable to infer base url".

I just changed version number from 2.9.2 to 2.9.0. 
On version 2.9.2 it is working fine.

UPDATE 2 - api-docs are getting generated and accessible however swagger-ui is not able to refer base url and if we provide it the api url manually then we can see that its able to get swagger resources(Response code 200) however nothing is displayed on Swagger UI.

Please provide your inputs.

Thanks,
RS

Answer (score 0):

You can use "https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mangofactory/swagger-springmvc" for JAVA 7. I working fine!

Comment: hey, thanks but not looking to explore any other library right now.

Comment: it is the previous version of springfox. it support for jdk 7. You can see history the release swagger.

Comment: Its not maintained i think, last release was on Mar, 2015.
whereas springfox last java 7 release was this year only